# Intellij IDEA can find maven dependency but can't download it

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, cmusphinx

I am currently trying to build an application based on CMU Sphinx using Intellij (Community).

Following the documentation on http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialsphinx4, I tried to download the package from the maven repo in Intellij by going to project structures, libraries, then the + sign. I selected Maven from the dropdown, and searched for sphinx4.

From the list that appeared, I selected edu.cmu.sphinx:sphinx4-core:5prealpha-SNAPSHOT. I clicked ok, and was soon confronted with a "no files were downloaded" error.

Any suggestions on what to try next?

Comment: You could try to add the dependency to your pom.xml manually. Intellij should ask you if you want to import it, or if you should have enabled autoimport, it would download it automatically. If that fails, too, you might run maven in the bash. The error message is probably more detailed

Comment: I'm not able to find the pom.xml file in the Intellij project. I started this project off of the project template in Intellij. Is it in a hidden directory?

Comment: Ok, Idea seems to manage that internally. Are you sure Idea knows about the repository? In the menu bar, go to File -> Settings, then search for Maven, unfold the submenus and choose "Repositories". Make sure you find the "snapshots-repo" in the list "Artifactory or Nexus Service URLs" from the tutorial there.

Comment: The repository is definitely ok. No problem downloading the artifact with Intellij IDEA, however as a manual entry in my pom.xml

Comment: I did not know that idea maintains a separate list of snapshot repos. I'll check that. Thank you!